# How to select the last row from one table then update the last row of another one?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing this

```
    UPDATE table1
    SET table1.col1 = table2.col2
    FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table1) AND table2.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table2);
```

I have a syntax error, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You are using non-MySQL join syntax for the `update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is unique in table1:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
    SET t1.col1 = (select t2.col2 from table2 t2 order by id desc limit 1) 
    ORDER BY t1.id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

This updates the "last" row in `table1` (by `id`) with the "last" row in `table2` (by `id`).

Your syntax doesn't work in multiple ways:

- MySQL does not support the `FROM` clause in `UPDATE`.
- MySQL does not allow you to reference the table being updated in a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL

```
   update table1
    cross join (
        select col2
        from table2
        order by id desc
        limit 1) as A
    inner join (
        select id
        from table1
        order by id desc
        limit 1) as B on (B.id = table1.id)
    set table1.col1 = A.col2
```